# GET request to a local IP in C with sockets

Tags: c, sockets, get, host, replit

I am trying to put together a C code that makes an HTTP `GET` request to a local IP address (in my network) that has a webpage runing on port 80. The request should return the `index.html`.

**The code works for a website with a real IP that has a DNS** (I have tested with `www.olx.ro` and its IP), but when I try to put the local IP (which is 10.74.4.10), I get a 400 Bad Request response..

This is the code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
  int byte_count;
  int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
  char recvBuff[9000];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
      return 1;
    }
  else printf("Created socket successfully.\n");

  printf("\n");

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.74.4.10");
  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
      return 1;
    }
  else printf("Connected successfully. \n ");

  printf("\n \n");

  char *header = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:10.74.4.10:80\r\n\r\n";
  send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);

  byte_count = recv(sockfd,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff),0);
  printf("Received %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
  printf("\n");
  printf("%.*s",byte_count,recvBuff);  

  return 0;
}
```

If I change `inet_addr("10.74.4.10")` to  `inet_addr("2.16.128.73")`, and `"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:10.74.4.10:80\r\n\r\n"` to `"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:www.olx.ro:80\r\n\r\n"`, then the code works as intended.

Also, I would like to mention I use Repl.it as C compiler.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the code stops at `connect()`. I have tried using `bind()`, still doesn't work. Maybe it's because I am trying to connect to a privileged port (80), with an online C compiler that cannot have root access?

Answer (score 1):

> ... but when I try to put the local IP (which is 10.74.4.10), I get a 400 Bad Request response.

While you send a valid HTTP request you tell the server using the `Host` header that you want to access the hostname 10.74.4.10 configured at the server. If this works or not depends on the servers configuration. For example if the server is configured to only accept requests for the name `example.com` and to consider everything else wrong it will only accept requests with `Host: example.com` but not with `Host: 10.74.4.10` even if this might be the IP address of the server.

> ...  I forgot to mention, the code stops at connect()

This makes no sense at at all. If you get a `400 Bad Request` as you first claim the connection to the site need to be successful first, which means it could not have stopped in `connect`.

Comment: FYI, the `Host` header is not officially defined in HTTP 1.0, which the code is using. `Host` is required only in HTTP 1.1+.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: While `Host` is in theory not required by HTTP/1.0 it is still needed when doing a HTTP request against a server which hosts multiple domains on the same IP address - since without it the server does not know which domain the client wants to access. Historically the browsers first implemented HTTP/1.0, then HTTP/1.0 with Host header and then HTTP/1.1. This is actually the same with SNI in TLS: it was not required until TLS 1.3 but still it is actually needed when accessing any CDN or other multi-domain servers.

Comment: Let me clarify:

FIrst, 400 bad request was happening when the i put "...Host: *some real IP, not local*", with both HTTP1.0 and 1.1.
Second, the code stopped at connect() when inet_addr() had a local IP address

Comment: @MihneaPaul: I see - in the first case you likely accessed an existing server but provided a Host header not expected by this server. In the second case where the connect is hanging the server you are trying to reach either does not exist at all (they don't magically exist on all IP addresses) or is blocked by a firewall. You should get similar problems if you use a browser from the same machine to the same target.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I had a comment about this but apparently it was deleted..thing is, the problem seemed to have been 1) the port 80 - being privileged and 2) the method connect() should have been bind(). I created a react app on port 3000, and the bind() worked, but now the program exists because of the send() method, with no explanation..

Comment: @MihneaPaul: I don't really understand what you are talking about.You don't need to use `bind` when you `connect` at all (OS will choose an appropriate source IP and port by itself) and you don't need any specific privileges to `connect` to a privileged port (browser can do it to!). These problems are relevant for the server side only - but you are talking about a client here. I recommend to actually try with your browser or with `curl`, `wget` and similar - if these cannot make a HTTP request to the specific server then your code will not be able to do it either.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich connect() gave me "permission denied", bind() worked fine.

Comment: @MihneaPaul: *"... connect() gave me "permission denied"..."* - I doubt that. Please provide the exact (but minimal) code which resulted in `connect` returning permission denied. And this statement also conflicts with your statement that `connect` hangs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, you were right, it was connect failed, not permission denied. Sorry. But still, the socket binds correctly, but the send() is the problem. As I mentioned before..

Comment: @MihneaPaul: "...but the send() is the problem..."* - this is a new one. So far you mentioned problems with `connect` hanging (likely no such server or firewalled, other clients like browsers will not work either) and with receiving the wrong response (since you've send the wrong request as I explained in my answer). You did not mention any problems with `send` so far.

Comment: Yes I did, in the comment where I specified about the port 80, and the react app on port 3000 (6 comments above). I also had a bunch of comments about this yesterday, but someone deleted them.

Comment: @MihneaPaul: yes, it was in the comment to which I said that I don't really understand what you are talking about. It made no sense for me. Apart from that, you don't even catch errors on `send` in your code so how can you notice that it fails there?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What exactly made no sense? I am not a C dev, so I am trying my best. I assumed it failes there because every printf() before works, and every printf() after send() does not do anything. So I deduced the code can only fail there.

Comment: *"fails"* means that the function actually returns an error, not that the function does not do what you expect (but don't describe what you expect). See [man send](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html). What you describe in terms of `printf` seems to be that the program is either hanging there or that your program crashed or that it is hanging inside the `recv` since there is no `printf` between `send` and `recv`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am constantly trying to solve the issue, therefore when I said the code exists because of send(), it's because I added printf bettween send() and recv(), and nothing is printed. Should I update the code in my question..?

Comment: @MihneaPaul: unfortunately these various attempts to solve the problem make your question unclear and a moving and blurry target since you show only one code but show results and problems from variations of the code. I recommend to 1. verify that the target URL is reachable from your client with a known good web client, preferable curl. Include the output of `curl -v` into your question for comparison. 2. Show the exact code you've used and describe in detail how and where it fails, verify the return from all connect, send.... . use perror to show error details.

Comment: I will try to debug, and update my findings. Thank you for your patience in helping me find a solution!

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So the first problem was the online compiler, it did not want to connect for some reason. I installed cygwin and compiled the code with gcc, and thus the connection to a local IP worked. The second problem with     send() was resolved after I changed the header to    GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n.

In conclusion, thank you for your responses, I learned a lot!